Mechanical rough-in / dryer vent
Me and my dad are building my house primarily by ourselves and making due with his prior knowledge and my degree from YouTube university and my post graduate in Reddit institute of higher learning. We failed our mechanical rough in because the dryer recessed vent is oval not round; I think I've found a round one available online and ordered it but won't know until it arrives (why are 99% of them oval if it's not allowed?) and our 4" pipe is 30ga and needs to be 28ga or better. Why does Lowe's and Home Depot only sell 30 if it's not allowed.... Anyone know where I can get 26/28ga 4" vent pipe for a reasonable price? Located in Fayetteville, NC

It may be that your local jurisdiction has stricter requirements. And it is also possible that existing homes are grandfathered, including replacement of exact same parts for repairs, but that new homes have stricter requirements.

Did you try your local HVAC supply house? The nearest one to me has 4 inch in both 30 gauge and 26 gauge in stock.
